# XML - Sort based on reversed words of sentence with XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<students>
  <student>
    <name>Clark Johnson</name>
  </student>
  <student>
    <name>John Doe</name>
  </student>
  <student>
    <name>Andy Ng</name>
  </student>
</students>
```

I already know that if I use `xsl:sort`, it would output

```
Andy Ng
Clark Johnson
John Doe
```

However, I want it to sort based on reversed words (Clark Johnson would be Johnson Clark, John Doe would be Doe John and Andy Ng would be Ng Andy) and output like this:

```
John Doe
Clark Johnson
Andy Ng
```

How can I achieve this with XSLT 1.0? I already have a template that can reverse the words but I don't know how to implement it in sorting. Here is the template:

```
<xsl:template name="reverse">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:if test="contains($text, ' ')">
      <xsl:call-template name="reverse">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, ' ')"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($text, ' '), ' ')"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you could look at it:

**XSLt 1.0 (+EXSLT node-set function)**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/students">
    <!-- pre-process -->
    <xsl:variable name="students">
        <xsl:for-each select="student">
            <student name="{name}">
                <xsl:call-template name="reverse">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="name"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </student>  
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output -->
    <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($students)/student">
        <xsl:sort/>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="reverse">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:if test="contains($text, ' ')">
      <xsl:call-template name="reverse">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, ' ')"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($text, ' '), ' ')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```